# Reinstalled Spectre R library but facing errors executing functions

Tags: linux, spectre

I reinstalled RStudio and all the previously existing packages were gone so I reinstalled them. However, when I run the pipeline provided by the previous worker, I get an error for the line  spectre::package.check() where the error is Error: 'package.check' is not an exported object from 'namespace:spectre'.

I am a student trying to learn dry labs and have not a lot of experience with R. I am using Ubuntu Linux.

I tried running a data analysis for Cytof. Usually, it would run flawless but with the recent changes I am failing to run it.